# Why is the interpreter call the variable i a local variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
stack = []
i=0
def push(val):
    stack.append(val)
    i+=1

def popout():
    del stack[i-1]

def maximum ():
    print(f"{i} elements present")


push(3)
push(4)
maximum()
```

In python interpreter it says :

> UnboundLocalError: local varibale i is referrenced before assignment.

Where as I have declared I globally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assign to a variable in a function, then Python assumes it is a local.

If you don't want that, add `global i` in the function:

```
def push(val):
    global i
    stack.append(val)
    i+=1
```

That said, that is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`i+=1` assignment created a new local variable `i` inside the `push` function.

If you want to use the global variable `i` use the `global` keyword.

```
def push(val):
    global i
    stack.append(val)
    i+=1
```